# Make the date display in different format to the standard MySQL y-m-d

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 'date' field in a MySQL table - its structure is 'DATE'. When I echo this out it displays as the standard year-month-day e.g. 2013-04-23. How do I alter the PHP to display it as Day-Month-Year and preferably with the month name displayed e.g. 23-April-2013.

this is the query

```
$sql = 'SELECT headline, story, date, name
FROM tpf_news
INNER JOIN tpf_parks ON tpf_news.park_id = tpf_parks.park_id ORDER BY date DESC' ;
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
```

this is the foreach loop

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
$news[] = array(
'headline' => $row['headline'],
'story' => $row['story'],
'date' => $row['date'],
'name' => $row['name']
);
}
```

And this is the PHP code currently used to display the date.

```
<?php echo $new['name'] , ' ', $new['date']; ?>
```

How to I go about making this happen?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL can do this work for you, using DATE_FORMAT()

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
DATE_FORMAT( date , '%d-%M-%Y' )
```

Answer (score 3):

Use MySQL's [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format your date in your query:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, "$e-%M-%Y") AS date
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it in PHP, the other suggestions may be better as they do it directly in MySQL. Depends what you want I guess.

$fixed_date = date('d-F-Y',strtotime($new['date']));

Should do it.